# Determine the equation of a line in the complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $z: Im(\frac{z-2i}{z-3})=0$, show that this is the equation of a line.

I know that the equation of a line can be given by:

$Re(z)a+Im(z)b=c$

Now if the imaginary part equals zero, does that mean the equation of the line is the real axis line?

Or does it mean something else??

Comment: Hint: $\;\frac{z-2i}{z-3}\,$ is real $\iff \frac{z-2i}{z-3}=\overline{\left(\frac{z-2i}{z-3}\right)}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z = x + i y $, then

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
\dfrac{z - 2 i}{z - 3} &= \dfrac{ x + i (y - 2) }{ (x - 3) + i y } \\
&= \dfrac{ (x + i (y-2) ) ( (x - 3) - i y) }{ (x - 3)^2 + y^2 }\\
&= \dfrac{ ( x(x-3) + y(y-2) ) + i ( (y - 2)(x - 3) - x y ) }{(x-3)^2 + y^2} \\
\end{split}\end{equation} $

If $\text{Im}\left( \dfrac{z - 2 i}{z - 3} \right) = 0 $ then

$ (y - 2)(x - 3) - x y = 0 $

And this simplifies to

$ -2 x - 3y + 6 = 0 $

or

$ 2 x + 3 y - 6 = 0 $

which is an equation of a line.

Comment: I got up till your second line of working, after that, I am lost. So you are saying that $\frac{z-2i}{z-3}$ is a complex number as well?

Comment: What ??????????

Comment: Nvm, I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Rationalize the denominator by multiplying numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

$\frac{z-2i}{z-3}=\frac{(z-2i)(\bar{z}-3)}{z\bar{z}-9}=0\implies z\bar{z}\ne9.$

$z\bar{z}-3z-2i\bar{z}+6i=0$

$z=x+iy$

$x^2+y^2-3x-3iy-2ix+2y+6i=(x^2+y^2-3x+2y)+i(6-2x-3y)$

The imaginary part is $6-2x-2y=0$. This is the equation of a line.

So this is a line in the complex plane so that for a given complex number with real part $x$ and imaginary part $y$: $y=3-x$.

So the slope is $-1$, and the lin intersects the imaginary axis near $y=3$. That point is removed though by previous arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a vectorial representation on the Argand plane, the equation $  \ \mathfrak{Im} \large{ \left(\frac{z-2i}{z-3} \right) } \normalsize{ \ = \ 0 } \ $ can be interpreted as saying that the vector from $ \ 2i \ $ to $ \ z \ $ is a *real scalar multiple* of the vector from $ \ 3 \ $ to $ \ z \ \ , \ $ which means that these two vectors are parallel or anti-parallel for all $ \ z \ $ in this locus of points. But this is only possible for the points that lie on the line which *passes through* $ \ 0 + 2i \ $ and $ \ 3 + 0i \ \ . \ $

We could describe this locus in various ways:

• writing the two specified points as $ \ (0 \ , \ 2) \ $ and $ \ (3 \ , \ 0) \ \ , \ $ a possible direction vector is $ \ \langle \ 3 - 0 \ , \ 0 - 2 \ \rangle \ = \ \langle \ 3 \ , \ -2 \ \rangle \ , \ $ giving us a parametric expression for $ \ z \ = \ x + iy \ \ , $ $ x \ = \ 3s \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ 2 - 2s \ \   $ (this places the points at $ \ s \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ s \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ respectively -- alternative choices are possible) ;

• the slope in the Argand plane is $ \ \frac{2i \ - \ 0}{0 \ - \ 3} \ = \ -\frac{2i}{3} \ \ , \ $ producing the equation for the line
$ yi - 0 \ = \ -\frac{2i}{3} · (x - 3) \ \rightarrow \ yi \ = \ 2i -  \frac{2i}{3} · x \ \ ; $

• for $ \ z \ = \ \alpha + \beta·i \ \ , \ $ the vector relation described in the first paragraph is $ \ \langle \ \alpha \ , \ \beta - 2 \ \rangle \ = \ \lambda · \langle \ \alpha - 3 \ , \ \beta \ \rangle \ \ , \ $ from which we obtain
$$ \alpha \ \ = \ \ \lambda·(\alpha \ - \ 3) \ \ \ , \ \ \ \beta \ - \ 2 \ \ = \ \ \lambda·\beta \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{\beta \ - \ 2}{\beta} \ \ = \ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{2}{\beta}$$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha \ \ = \ \ \left(1 \ - \ \frac{2}{\beta} \right)·(\alpha \ - \ 3) \ \ = \ \ \alpha \ - \ 3 \ - \ \frac{2 \alpha}{\beta} \ + \ \frac{6}{\beta} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \  0 \ \ = \ \  -  3 \ - \ \frac{2 \alpha}{\beta} \ + \ \frac{6}{\beta} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2\alpha \ + \ 3\beta \ \ = \ \ 6 \ \ , \ \ \beta \ \neq \ 0 $$

(the equation does correctly yield $ \ \alpha \ = \ 3 \ \ , \ \ \beta \ = \ 0 \ , \ $ though).